# Apache CXF Logging Interceptors Not Triggered on Weblogic on Spring Boot App

Tags: java, web-services, spring-boot, weblogic, cxf

I'm using Apache CXF to implement Bottom Up Soap WS on a Spring Boot application. Everything was working fine until deployed on Weblogic (12.2.1.3.0). The issue is that the LoggingInterceptors that I'm trying to use are not being exceuted at all.

First problem was acctually a nullpointer on a @Autowired injection on the WebService implementation class. To fix that I use some workaround that I founded here on StackO. Appears that weblogic start separated context loaders, one for spring and all the beans and one for CXF. So when the webservice impl class is called via wsdl url the injection are not done. After fixing this issue, the WS works fine, but the logging interceptors added via spring boot configuration are not triggered. And one important feature of the application is the ability to store the soap request response on the database. So it's important that the Interceptors chain works.

The Spring Boot config class:

```
@Configuration
public class LmsReloadCXFWSConfig implements ServletContextInitializer{

    private static WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    public static WebApplicationContext getCurrentWebApplicationContext() {
        return webApplicationContext;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistration() {
        return new ServletRegistrationBean(new CXFServlet(), "/*");
    }

    @Bean
    public LoggingInInterceptor logInInterceptor() {
        return new LmsReloadWSInboundInterceptor();
    }
    @Bean
    public LoggingOutInterceptor  logOutInterceptor() {
        return new LmsReloadWSOutboundInterceptor();
    }

    @Bean(name=Bus.DEFAULT_BUS_ID)
    public SpringBus springBus() {   
        SpringBus springBus = new SpringBus();  
        return springBus;
    }

    @Bean
    public LmsReloadWebService lmsReloadWebService() {
        LmsReloadWebService lmsReloadWebService =  new LmsReloadWebServiceImpl();     
        return lmsReloadWebService;
    }

    @Bean
    public Endpoint endpoint() {
        EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(springBus(), lmsReloadWebService());   
        endpoint.getInInterceptors().add(logInInterceptor());
        endpoint.getOutInterceptors().add(logOutInterceptor());
        endpoint.publish("/Soap");
        return endpoint;
    }
}
```

Both are Custom Interceptors that extends LoggingInInterceptor and LoggingOutInterceptor:

```
public class LmsReloadWSInboundInterceptor extends LoggingInInterceptor{
...
}

public class LmsReloadWSOutboundInterceptor extends LoggingOutInterceptor{    
...
}
```

The Web Service interface and implementation:

```
@WebService(name = "LmsServiceInterface", targetNamespace=LmsReloadUtil.LMSRELOAD_NAMESPACE_ORI)
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.WRAPPED)
public interface LmsReloadWebService {
...
}

@WebService(portName = "LmsServicePort", serviceName = "Soap", targetNamespace = LmsReloadUtil.LMSRELOAD_NAMESPACE_ORI, endpointInterface = "com.dell.lms.reload.ws.LmsReloadWebService")
public class LmsReloadWebServiceImpl implements LmsReloadWebService {

    @Autowired
    private LmsReloadService lmsReloadService;

    @Autowired
    private LmsReloadLoggingService lmsReloadLoggingService;

    public LmsReloadWebServiceImpl() {
        AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor bpp = new AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor();
        WebApplicationContext currentContext = LmsReloadCXFWSConfig.getCurrentWebApplicationContext();
        bpp.setBeanFactory(currentContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory());
        bpp.processInjection(this);
    }   
    ...
}
```

The CXF version on my pom.xml is 3.2.7

What I need to do is to get those interceptors working so I can save the request and response on the database. Again, the application works fine and coomplete when executed useing the spring boot tomcat started in Eclipse. And since the issue with the Autowired on the WebService Impl Class, I think is something related to the way weblogic depoloy the application. Distinct context loaders.

Being investigating this problem during the last week, found a lot of possible solution, tried all but with no success.

Comment: I see that Weblogic is providing two WSDL url, one generated by JAX_WS and one by Spring ( I Believe ), the first one is the one where the interceptors do not work.

Comment: JAX-WS > http://hostname:port/LmsService/Soap?wsdl

Comment: http://hostname:port/LmsService/LmsService/Soap?wsdl

Comment: Did you find any solution to this? Stuck with same issue